# Find three complete integrals of $pq=px + qy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve using charpit auxiliary equations

$p=$ partial derivative of $z$ w.r.t. $x$

$q=$ partial derivative of $z$ w.r.t. $y$

Comment: your thoughts, ideas or efforts?

Comment: Using Charpit , I think you'll get only one solution, and I doubt that this has three different complete integrals.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409542/the-equation-pq-px-qy-has-more-than-one-complete-integral/4863016#4863016.