# The equation $ pq = px + qy $ has more than one complete integral.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Show that the equation $ pq = px + qy $ has more than one complete integral.

Using Charpit Method I find $az = \frac{1}{2}(y + ax)^{2} + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integrating constant. How could I find another? Is there any theorem to show for existence of more than one complete integral?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

$$pq=xp+yq\quad ;\quad p=\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}\quad ;\quad q=\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial y}$$
If we look only for particular solutions there is no need for the characteristic method. Simple inspection draw to try a function on the form $z=f(xy)$ for example.
$$p=yf'\quad;\quad q=xf'\quad;\quad xy(f')^2=x(yf')+y(xf')=2xyf'\quad;\quad f'=2$$
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=2xy+c}$$
This is sufficient to show that there is more than one solution $az=\frac12(y+ax)^2+b$ .

Note that this solution $az=\frac12(y+ax)^2+b$ can be obtained directly in searching particular solutions on the form $z=f(\alpha y+\beta x)$.

With the Charpit-Lagrange method the system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{x-q}=\frac{dy}{y-p}=\frac{dp}{-p}=\frac{dq}{-q}=\frac{dz}{(x-q)p+(y-p)q}$$
Note that the last fraction is of no interest since this is the combination of the two first fractions and equivalent to the obvious $dz=p\,dx+q\,dy$.

No need to repeat here the well known method which for example is explained in full details in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U51hN02LYrw

The solution $z=2xy+c$ is straightforward in observing that the system of ODEs is satisfied with $p=2y$ and $q=2x$:
$$\frac{dx}{x-(2x)}=\frac{dy}{y-(2y)}=\frac{d(2y)}{-(2y)}=\frac{d(2x)}{-(2x)}$$
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2y\implies z=2xy+g(y)\quad$ and $\quad\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2x\implies z=2xy+h(x)$

$g(y)=h(x)\implies =c \quad\implies z=2xy+c$

Comment: but complete integral must contain two arbitrary constant for $z = 2xy + c$, its just one.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to obtain other solutions with two arbitrary constants with the ansatz $z=xf(y)+a$ ($a$ is one of the constants); then $p=z_x=f(y)$, $q=z_y=xf'(y)$, and the PDE $pq=px+qy$
becomes
$$
f(y)xf'(y)=f(y)x+xf'(y)y. \tag{1}
$$
Dividing both sides of $(1)$ by $x$ and rearranging terms, we obtain the ODE
$$
f'(y)=\frac{f(y)}{f(y)-y}. \tag{2}
$$
Rewriting $(2)$ as
$$
\frac{dy}{df}=\frac{f-y}{f}=1-\frac{y}{f}, \tag{3}
$$
we obtain a linear ODE for $y(f)$, whose general solution is
$$
y=\frac{f}{2}-\frac{b}{f}. \tag{4}
$$
Solving $(4)$ for $f$, we find two solutions,
$$
f_{\pm}(y)=y\pm\sqrt{y^2+b}. \tag{5}
$$
This gives us two solutions to the PDE containing two arbitrary constants:
$$
z_{\pm}(x,y)=x\left(y\pm \sqrt{y^2+b}\right)+a. \tag{6}
$$
Needless to say, the ansatz $z=f(x)y+a$ yields another two solutions,
$$
\tilde{z}_{\pm}(x,y)=\left(x\pm \sqrt{x^2+b}\right)y+a. \tag{7}
$$